# Pandas sort and grouping

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a data set like with players and scores like the following:

```
Team    Player  Scorer
raptors jim     32
mingos  john    31
dinos   sue     34
raptors joe     43
mingos  mark    56
dinos   luke    23
```

I want to sort them based on the lowest scorer.  However, i need the teams to be grouped together.  So the lowest scorer will be first and the rest of his team would be next.  Followed by the second lowest scorer and his team like below:

```
Team    Player  Scorer
dinos   luke    23
dinos   sue     34
mingos  john    31
mingos  mark    56
raptors jim     32
raptors joe     43
```

Aslo, if I could have a summary with just the lowest scorer for each team in the same order as the teams appear above:
summary:

```
Team    Player  Scorer
dinos   luke    23
mingos  john    31
raptors jim     32
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you having trouble?

Comment: Are you looking sort_values ?   and df.sort_values().drop_duplicates()?

Answer (score 0):

For sorting:

```
df.sort_values(["Team", "Scorer"])
```

For getting the lowest score within each team:

```
df.groupby("Team").min().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try these:

Answer 1 (sorting):

```
df.groupby(['Team','Player']).agg({'Scorer': min}).reset_index()
```

Answer 2 (lowest score):

```
df.groupby('Team').apply(min).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This example working for me:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([{"Team": "raptors", "Player":"jim", "Scorer":32},{"Team": "mingos", "Player":"john", "Scorer":31}, {"Team": "dinos",  "Player":"sue", "Scorer":34},{"Team": "raptors", "Player":"joe",  "Scorer":43},{"Team": "mingos", "Player":"mark", "Scorer":56},{"Team": "dinos", "Player":"luke", "Scorer":23}], 
            columns=["Team", "Player", "Scorer"])

df=df.sort_values(["Team", "Scorer"])
df.groupby("Team").min().reset_index()
```

shows:

```
    Team    Player  Scorer
0   dinos   luke    23
1   mingos  john    31
2   raptors jim     32
```

Comment: This works but if "0  raptors    jim      32" was changed to 30 the raptors should get prined before the mingos since the mingos lowest scorer is 31.  Is there a way add that additonal sort.